# ¿Que sería el CUSTOMER_ID?

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy intentando subscribir a un usuario a un plan una vez que consigo una token, y no logro encontrar en la documentación cual es el CUSTOMER_ID.

Me podrían indicar como conseguirlo?

```
curl -X POST \
    -H 'accept: application/json' \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
'https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/subscriptions?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' \
    -d '{
            "plan_id": "PLAN_ID",
            "payer": {
                    "id": "CUSTOMER_ID" <--- ??
            }
    }'
```

Gracias!

Comment: Probablemente sea un identificador que te dan para acceder a su API. ¿Has preguntado a su soporte?

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que consultaras el soporte de la API por la que preguntas ya que no todo el mundo ha de estas familiarizado con ella en este sitio.

Comment: @IvanBotero Mercado Pago ofrece soporte técnico también por consultas en este sitio :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customer es un concepto de MercadoPago que hace referencia a tus usuarios o clientes registrados para tu aplicación, es decir debes crear un customer para poder usuarlo posteriormente con alguna accion de la API.

Aqui la documentacion de customers : https://www.mercadopago.com.co/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/customers-and-cards/

Una vez registrado el customer puedes buscarlo desde un mail u otros datos para obtener su id que lo identifica en MercadoPago.

```
curl -X GET \
        -H 'accept: application/json' \
        'https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/customers/search?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' \
        -d 'email=your.payer@email'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que navegar entre los objetos que te trae el *callback* a la *API*.

En la  documentación está definido así:

> Retrieves information about a subscription
>   GET
>   /v1/subscriptions/:id
>
> Creates a new subscription
>   POST
>   /v1/subscriptions
>
> Updates a subscription
>   PUT
>   /v1/subscriptions/:id